# Email is not going to private domain

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am trying to send an email to all the staff members once particular action triggers. Everything works fine. However, I have noticed that email is not going to those who have our domain name email address. Other than that, I have tried to check that the one who use gmail, yahoo or hotmail receives the email. Most interesting thing is that, they can see the list of all email addresses including those who do not receive it. I am just wondering, what could be the reason for it ? Is there any restriction for sending any emails to private domains ? I do not reckon. I am using the `codeigniter email library` and following is my code.

```
 $config = Array(
          'mailtype' => 'html',
          'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
          'wordwrap' => TRUE
        );  

          $message = $this->load->view('request/template', $d, true);

          $this->load->library('email', $config);
          $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
          $this->email->from('no-reply@austecservices.com.au','Austec Services Pty Ltd'); // change it to yours
          $this->email->to('xxxxx@austecservices.com.au, xxxx@yahoo.com');// change it to
          $this->email->bcc('xxxxx@gmail.com');
          $this->email->subject($company[0]->title.": ".$this->userSession->given_name." ".$this->userSession->surname." raised an ad-hoc request for ".$site_name);
          $this->email->message($message);

           if(!$this->email->send()) {
                  show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
             }
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Is the message appearing in the spam/bulk folder?

Comment: I checked that one too. Its not there

Comment: Can you send a different message from the same address to your email account? Is it appearing then either in inbox or spam/bulk?

Answer (score 0):

please try this code:

```
$mail['fordetail'] = array(
'name'=> $name,
'email'=> $email,
'content'=>$content,
);

$txtEmail = $this->load->view('email',$mail,true);  
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from($this->config->item('team'));

$this->email->to($cusdata->email);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($txtEmail);   
$this->email->send();
```